# Is there any python operator that equivalent to javascript triple equal?

Tags: python

I tried to do this but fail:

```
File "<input>", line 1
    1==='1'
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there any workaround?

Comment: can you show the code

Comment: Arguably `===` in JavaScript only exists as a workaround for `==` being horribly broken. Likewise for PHP.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The ordinary `==` operator in Python already works much like the `===` operator in JavaScript, in that it won't do string conversions. However, it does *not* compare types.

```
>>> 1 == '1'
False
>>> 1 == 1.0
True
>>> 1 == True
True
```

So we would say that Python doesn't have an exact equivalent to the JavaScript `==` or `===` operators.  The way Python uses `==`, without a `===` operator, is the norm. JavaScript (and PHP) are a bit unusual.

This last bit about `bool` might be a bit surprising, but `bool` is a subclass of `int` in Python.

Comment: `1 === true` is false in javascript, for example.

Comment: Well, `1 == true` in Python because `bool` is a subclass of `int`… that’s a bit of a quirk there, one it shares with C, for example.

Comment: * `1 == true` is a `NameError` , `1 == True` is indeed true, which is also true for `1.0`,  `0o1` and other number `1`  formats. If you absolutely must, you can test if it's really a boolean `isinstance(True, (bool)` (is true) X `isinstance(1, (bool))` is false

Comment: @jave.web: `true` is obviously intended to be `True`

Answer (score 4):

Closest would maybe be the `is` operator. It returns `True` only if both variables point to the same object.

Comment: ...which is nothing like a comparison. `1000 is 500 + 500` returns false.

Comment: @spectras: *can* be false, but often won't be. Try it. (Original comment said `1000 is 1000`.)

Comment: @DietrichEpp> that example never is. It just so happens that CPython pre-creates integers up to 256, so if you try with those you get True. With any other integer, you get False.

Comment: @spectras: Your example was `1000 is 1000` before you edited it, which will be true on CPython because of how the compiler works.

Comment: @DietrichEpp> that's why I edited it immediately (perhaps I did it as you were commenting since you commented quickly). The point was `is` is not a comparison, is not intended to be and does not work as such, so this answer is wrong.

Comment: @spectras: I agree that it's not a comparison of value, but other implementations of Python are free to return true for `1000 is 500 + 500`, and the fact that it is false in the current version of CPython is not a promise.

Comment: @spectras Weird. The documentation places it in a section titled "Comparisons"

Comment: @DietrichEpp> For proving a statement is wrong, one example contradicting it is enough.

Comment: @joeb> It is a comparison. It compares the identity of objects. Not their value. In the `1000 is 500+500` counterexample, what happens is two different integer objects get created, both holding the value 1000. Yet they are different objects, so `is` returns false.

Comment: @spectras If they wanted to compare values, they already have everything they need with `==` -- they asked about going beyond that and comparing types as well. That being said, if two variables return `True` for an `is` comparison, that's more than just their values.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for. It is a comparison of object identity. That's why in Java you have `=` vs `equals()`.

Comment: FWIW it looks like `is` returns true for such arithmetic expressions as of Python 3.9.6, but also warns `SyntaxWarning: "is" with a literal. Did you mean "=="?`

Answer (score 0):

work around:
if a==b and type(a) == type(b):
# do something